# Using a control of parent formgroup inside nested formgroupname

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I am creating a form where I am using formgroupname inside a formgroup.

**Html:**

```
<form [formGroup]="parentForm">
  <div formGroupName="childGroup">
    <input type="text" formControlName="childControl1">
    <input type="text" formControlName="parentControl1">
    <input type="text" formControlName="childControl2">
  </div>
</form>
```

**Ts Code**

```
this.parentForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  parentControl1: new FormControl(),
  childGroup: this.formBuilder.group({
  childControl1: new FormControl(),
  childControl2: new FormControl(),
 })
})
```

I am getting following error.

**Error**: Cannot find control with path: 'childGroup -> parentControl1'

**Note:**
I can't change html structure. Need a workaround of can I achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"parentControl" not belong to ChildGroup

1. A workAround is use a getter

   ```
   get parentControl1():FormControl
   {
      return this.parentForm.get('parentControl1') as FormControl
   }
   ```

   And use `[formControl]`

   ```
   <div formGroupName="childGroup">
       <input type="text" formControlName="childControl1">
       <input type="text" [formControl]="parentControl1">
       <input type="text" formControlName="childControl2">
   </div>
   ```
2. Another workaround is use some like

   ```
   <div formGroupName="childGroup">
       <input type="text" formControlName="childControl1">
       <input type="text" [ngModel]="this.parentForm.get('parentControl1').value"
                          (ngModelChange)="this.parentForm.get('parentControl1')
                                                                  .setValue($event)"
                          [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"> 
       <input type="text" formControlName="childControl2">
   </div>
   ```